# best practise for connecting to a database server in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have been doing much research into this and was wondering what the best approach is, imagine the scenario where you have a WPF application that is being distributed to many users, this application has to connect to a database server. Connecting to a database is not a problem its how secure the connection is as external users will have access to the application.

within the app.config file connection strings can be pointed to the server, however releasing the password and server IP address is not a good idea. from research, other people recommended encrypting the data, but sure this is still got a degree of vulnerability.

the next approach is to use WCF, this i have limited knowledge on and not sure if this approach is correct.

Am I safe in encrypting the connection strings or is there more to it than that, I just want to be extra careful when dealing with sensitive data.

Comment: Encrypted things can be decrypted.  It may be difficult to do so, but it's possible.  So the information is still being given to the users.  You could have individual user accounts, or Windows authentication domain accounts, instead of a single service account.  Or you could not expose the database at all and instead have a server-side API application which obscures the database.  The client applications would connect to the API instead of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way is to add a server layer between your wpf app and the database. It can be a REST api or other web services as you like. In terms of technologies you can choose, wcf is one. But wcf is not easy to get started with if you do not have experience of dealing with services. I suggest to try Asp.Net's Web Api project to quickly establish a Rest Service (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-1 ).

This server layer will protect your database information (connection string etc). Also, allowing your application directly querying the database will potentially prevent the database from evolving -- for example, the insert query may break on the client side when you add a constraint on a table. Having a server in between can solve this future headache as you can update the server side implementation and database simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

In case of data sensitive, I would like to prefer SOA architecture will most suitable to you. WCF will be good option but think about RestFulWCF or WebApi2.0 (popular for multi platform support).

Hope this will help :)